# How come my code shifted the graph in Matplotlib many units to the right?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I just plotted my data the graph turned out fine. However, it was when I tried to graph the peak values that resulted in a strange error, where the new points are moved a lot further to the right than the original correct graph.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

r = csv.reader(open("/Users/briansong/Downloads/Sonar 2020-10-25 11-27-57/Echo location.csv"))
lines = list(r)
distance = []
cc = []
for i in range(1, len(lines)): 
    a = lines[i][0]
    b = lines[i][1]
    if b == "":
        break
    index1 = a.find("E")
    index2 = b.find("E")
    num1 = float(a[:index1])
    num2 = float(b[:index2])
    distance.append(num1 * 10 ** float(a[index1 + 1:]))
    cc.append(num2 * 10 ** float(b[index2 + 1:]))

plt.ylim(top = 3.0)
plt.xlabel("Distance")
plt.ylabel("CC")

x = np.array(distance)
y = np.array(cc)
graph = np.concatenate((x, y))
peaks, _ = find_peaks(graph, prominence = 1)

plt.plot(graph)
plt.plot(peaks, graph[peaks], 'x')

plt.plot(distance, cc)
plt.show()
```

[Picture of graph green is original and correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hufAj.png)

Comment: in one `plot` call you provide x-values. In the other, you do not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you concatenate x and y to calculate the peaks.
You could just do:

```py
x = np.array(distance)
y = np.array(cc)
peaks, _ = find_peaks(y, prominence = 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(peaks, y[peaks], 'x')
plt.show()
```

The offset between the two graphs in your plot were, because for the 'wrong' graph you first plotted your x values on the y axis and then you plotted the values you wanted to plot, due to the concatenate.